# "find" command gets killed when trying to work on thousands of files

Tags: find, recursive

I am trying to create PBF out of thousands of OSC changeset files using `osmium` tool. I have written a Bash script for doing this task using Jenkins.

1. I am merging all OSC files into one master OSC files
2. then applying that OSC to PBF.

But I am facing issues when trying to merge large amount of OSC files into master at once. I use the following command

```
osmium merge-changes -v -o $destination/all-"$execution_tag".osc.gz $(find $_osc -name '*.osc') --overwrite
```

but this command is being killed by OS when it's trying to work on large directory with more than 12k files.

I have many directories and sub-directories where I am trying to recursively find all `*.osc` files, and sometimes it's so many files that I get the following error:

```
[ 0:01] Opening output file...
[ 0:01] Reading change file contents...
***/tmp/jenkins91826773077502863.sh: line 36: 329085 Killed                  osmium merge-changes -v -o $_osc_processor/all-"$execution_tag".osc.gz $(find $_osc -name '*.osc') --overwrite***
applying master osc change file to pbf ::
```

What can be the best way to approach this issue? Is there any other way I can recursively find all files in dir and sub-dir?

- I tried to replace `find` with a glob search (`/*/*.osc`) and it still got killed.
- Currently I am trying to run this command from parent directory having multiple sub directories with files. If I manually execute each sub directory it seems to work fine
- Is there a way, if I get certain path as input, I can search for all sub dir inside it, if sub dir exists then I run this command individually on each sub dir?

Comment: It seems that `find` works fine. Your `osmium` command gets killed, I guess because it has too many arguments.

Comment: @thanasisp or more likely the shell process that would eventually run `osmium` gets killed (maybe by the oom killer).

Comment: yes Stephane, I see [here](https://docs.osmcode.org/osmium/latest/osmium.html) a reference for memory usage.

Comment: i tried to replace find with blob search (/*/*.osc) and it still got killed. Currently i am trying to run this command from parent directory having multiple sub directories with files, 
if i manually execute each sub directory it seems to work fine, is there a way, if i get certain path as input, i can search for all sub dir inside it, if sub dir exists then i run this command individually on each sub dir?

Comment: The correct fix for this would be to call `osmium merge-changes` from `find ... -exec` with batches of found pathnames. Since I don't know `osmium` or whether it's possible to do what you want with batches of files with that tool, I can't provide a complete answer.